# werkzeug exception: ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Full stack below. Happening with Python 3.10.5 on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM. Using Werkzeug 2.1.2.

Any idea of the cause?

No problem on Windows 10 or an Ubuntu 18.04 NUC. Works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 VM with Python 3.6.5 and Werkzeug 1.0.1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 921, in read
    read = self._read(to_read)
ValueError: read of closed file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 140, in wrapper
    return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 290, in _parse_multipart
    form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 418, in parse
    for data in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 653, in _make_chunk_iter
    item = _read(buffer_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 923, in read
    return self.on_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 893, in on_disconnect
    raise ClientDisconnected()
werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just as it states, the client disconnected. The reason? could be several, they could have had a network problem, they could have clicked a different link, they could have navigated away. either way, the server could no longer talk to your client and finish the transfer of data.

It's the most annoying error in the world, you can't do anything about it.